# Getting 404 when running Karma Jasmine tests with code coverage

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner, karma-coverage

When running `ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless --code-coverage` on my Angular project, it aborts with a `404: /_karma_webpack_/main.js` error and shows "Unknown values" under the coverage summary.

I'm new to [TDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development) and I'm having trouble understanding what the issue is. I've pasted my karma configuration and the error log below.

**karma.conf.js:**

```javascript
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-junit-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage'),
      require('karma-sonarqube-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    jasmineHtmlReporter: {
      suppressAll: true // removes the duplicated traces
    },
    coverageReporter: {
    subdir: '.',
     dir: 'report/coverage',
     reporters: [
        { type: 'lcov'},
        { type: 'text-summary'}
      ]
    },
    junitReporter: {
      outputDir: 'report/junit',
      outputFile: 'junit-report.xml'
    },
    sonarqubeReporter: {
      basePath: 'src/app',
      outputFolder: 'report/junit',
      filePattern: '**/*.spec.ts',
      encoding: 'utf-8',
      legacyMode: false,
      reportName: 'sonar-report.xml'
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit', 'sonarqube'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    customLaunchers: {
      ChromeHeadless: {
        base: 'Chrome',
        flags: [
          '--headless',
          '--no-sandbox',
          '--disable-gpu',
          '--remote-debugging-port=9222'
        ]
      }
    },
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true,
  });
};
```

**Error log:**

```
30 06 2023 13:12:38.914:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v6.4.2 server started at http://localhost:9876/
30 06 2023 13:12:38.915:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers ChromeHeadless with concurrency unlimited
30 06 2023 13:12:38.932:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
30 06 2023 13:12:41.596:INFO [Chrome Headless 114.0.5735.199 (Windows 10)]: Connected on socket 2aM0rG6OXdudE58mAAAB with id 97727621
30 06 2023 13:12:41.788:WARN [web-server]: 404: /_karma_webpack_/main.js
Chrome Headless 114.0.5735.199 (Windows 10): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0.032 secs / 0 secs)
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS

=============================== Coverage summary ===============================
Statements   : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Branches     : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Functions    : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
Lines        : Unknown% ( 0/0 )
```

I've tried to set some `files` properties in *karma.conf.js* as other Stack Overflow answers have suggested, but nothing I've tried has worked yet.

Answer (score 0):

I compared my configurations to yours and I found this difference in the `dir` config:

```
dir: 'report/coverage'
```

Do this:

```
dir: require('path').join(__dirname, './report/coverage'),
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the Karma test runner is unable to locate the main.js file in the `_karma_webpack_` directory, which is resulting in a 404 error.

Verify the file configuration in `karma.conf.js` and ensure that the files array in your Karma configuration includes the correct paths to your test files, including the `main.js` file.

**Example:**

```
files: [
  { pattern: './src/test.ts', watched: false },
  { pattern: './src/_karma_webpack_/main.js', watched: true },
],
```

Check the `angular.json` configuration and make sure that the main property is correctly set in the architect `> build` section of your `angular.json` file. It should point to the entry point of your application, `src/main.ts`.

Verify the preprocessors configuration in `karma.conf.js` and ensure that the preprocessors section in your Karma configuration includes the correct paths to preprocess the files.

**Example:**

```
preprocessors: {
  './src/_karma_webpack_/main.js': ['coverage']
},
```

Check for any other errors or warnings and review the console output for any other error or warning messages that might provide more information about the issue. Sometimes I think there could be other misconfigurations or dependencies causing conflicts.

Apply any necessary adjustments to your Karma configuration based on your project structure and file locations. After making the changes, rerun the tests using `ng test --browsers ChromeHeadless --code-coverage` and see if the issue is still there.

Comment: This answer looks like ChatGPT

Comment: Hi, Sreeram Nair.  

Most or all of your last 11 answers appear likely to be entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). Many also have comments indicating that they are wrong in some respect. Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it. 

We do hope you'll stick around and continue to be a valuable part of our community by posting *your own* quality content. Thanks!

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly.